# REST API External user access

Tags: rest, access-rights

I'm currently trying to access a sharepoint site through the REST api using an external user from another organization.

The user has been added to the Site Members group with the `Edit` rights successfully. Tho, after retrieving an access token, I'm constantly getting this response:

```
GET https://<my-site>/_api/web # And all the other routes
{
  "error_description": "Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."
}
```

I allowed sharing on this site through the office 365 admin center but it seems like it's impossible to access it anyway.

I've been searching for this on google for a few hours now and I still can't get any results. I tried tweaking the settings in the Sharepoint admin center but nothing worked. Also, after going through the Sharepoint REST API documentation I couldn't find anything about this particular use case.

Is it possible to access the REST API of a site using a user that is external to the organization itself?

Comment: For accessing rest API with external user, Site must be shared with that user with minimum read permission.
and please replace ajax call '_api/web/webinfos' instead of '_api/web/webs'.

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is kinda late, but I hope it will help people that have the same problem with you and (previously).

When you need to get a token, you need to build a resource as a parameter. The resource format is:

AudienceID/host@realm

For example:

```
00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/tenant.sharepoint.com@17db9dca-542b-4942-9964-4816e2b6e26a
```

Note: `00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000` is static audience ID for Sharepoint. Check it out at [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-and-use-access-tokens-in-provider-hosted-high-trust-sharepoint-add-ins).

From my experience, I was wrong defined host value. Please check your host again.

The host value cannot contain protocol and path, it's a really pure hostname. Even when you are using custom site collection like as `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/application`, you just need the hostname (`tenant.sharepoint.com`) without path or slash in the end.